# Use "rmdir" functionality but keep specified directory

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-console

I would like the functionality of `rmdir /s` but I need to keep the specified directory. `rmdir /s` removes all files and sub directories in addition to the directory specified.

I've also tried using `del /s` but then I am left with empty folders in the specified directory. I need those folders removed as well.

Any guidance on how I can do this?

Comment: You mean you want to _empty_ a directory without deleting it?

Comment: You can use the rd command - answered below.

Comment: rd and rmdir are the same thing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest way would be to change directory to specified directory and invoke an rd command on the "." directory. Like:

```
cd toYourDirectory (or pushd toYourDirectory)
rd /q /s . 2> nul
```

- /q - ensures you wont be prompted
- /s - to do subfolders, files, so
  on..
- the "." - implies CURRENT directory
- 2>nul - ensures it won't report
  the error when the rd command attempts to remove itself (which is
  what you want)

Answer (score 1):

<3 for loops

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%F IN (`dir /b /a:d /s "C:\top\directory\" ^| FIND /v /i "C:\directory\to\omit"`) DO (
 rmdir /s "%%F"
)
```

and if you wish to strike dangerously, use the `/q` switch w/ `rmdir`  0.o

So lets say, you want to perform a `remdir /s` on `C:\Documents and Settings\Mechaflash\`, HOWEVER you wish to keep the `.\Mechaflash` folder (emptied)

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%F IN (`dir /b /a:d /s "C:\Documents and Settings\Mechaflash\" ^| FIND /v /i "C:\Documents and Settings\Mechaflash\"`) DO (
 rmdir /s "%%F"
)
DEL /Q /F "C:\Documents and Settings\Mechaflash\*"
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer; however, if I'm going to make two statements, I might as well use rmdir and mkdir.

Comment: Yeah... that for loop is way overkill LOL. rmdir and mkdir is the same exact effect. Now unless the folder in question has system/hidden files you would like to keep, then rmdir on the folder may not be ideal

Comment: You should never iterate over `dir` output in this way unless absolutely necessary. There are severe drawbacks regarding Unicode file names that are not present when iterating directly with `for`. In this case you could simply use a normal `for` loop with a conditional inside. Although I don't quite understand where you get the need to omit a directory anyway.

Comment: Using rmdir and mkdir will lose any special permissions (ACLs) on the directory.